# Fetching labels and metadata for sharepoint online documents from MS graph apis

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, sharepoint-api

1. Labels can be created for sharepoint online sites/document libraries. (Refer [Labels in sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/protect-sharepoint-online-files-with-office-365-labels-and-dlp))

How can we fetch labels for any document (or sites/DL) with Microsoft Graph API?

Currently I am fetching document details with below which is not providing any label info for the document-

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drives/<DRIVE_ID>/root/children
```

2. Along with above, Is it possible to fetch document metadata with MS graph api?
   (Refer [Managed Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/managed-metadata))

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following API to get labels and metadata(Based on my test, i cannot get the labels/metadata you pointed, no other official docs have clear explanation of these two points too):

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitem_get

If you cannot get the information by the expand=fields too, I'd suggest you to submit a feature request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Above api is for listItems. I wanted to get information for DriveItem (api- GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}), we are not getting any information with this api.

Comment: I have not saw API for the DriveItem suit your requirement. So I sugget to store the files in the document/list then try to use the list api to operate them. For separately user, we may store their file in the onedrive/onedrive-for-business,but for team use, we mostly store the files in the document library, so we can try the listitem API.